# MouseDown and touch screen

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the C# `MouseDown` event. When I use the touch screen to touch the mouse down label once, whenever I touch next will also trigger the event. But when I use the mouse to click it, all seems to be okay.

Here is my sample code for the label mouse down event:

```
lblEAForm = new Label();
lblEAForm.Name = "lblEAForm";
lblEAForm.Width = 240;
lblEAForm.Height = 250;
lblEAForm.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
lblEAForm.Margin = new Thickness(20);
lblEAForm.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/BorangEA.png")));
Grid.SetColumn(lblEAForm, 1);
Grid.SetRow(lblEAForm, 0);
lblEAForm.MouseDown += ShowGUIEAForm;
```

Here is the function that it should call:

```
public void msg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try making the `MessageBox` show up on `MouseUp` instead. `MouseDown` events are sometimes a bit wonky.

Comment: Are you using Mouse click event as well along with mousedown?

Comment: Thanks...i change to Mouse Up and everything fine now.